# How can I see the string with math random?

Tags: react-native

I have an array of strings. For example `const strings['hello', 'hi', 'good day']` and I am trying to pick one string in random. I see `LOG      91` in the console log but how do i see the string?

```
function Generate() {
    const randomString = Math.floor(Math.random() * (scenario.length))
    return randomString
}

function MostLikely(this: any) {
  return (
    <ImageBackground
      source={require('../../../assets/banner.jpg')}
      style={styles.image}>
      
  <Text>{}</Text>
      <Button title='Generate' onPress={() => console.log(Generate())} />
    </ImageBackground>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using functional components, you can make use [useState](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usestate) and [useCallback](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback) to get what you want:

```
const scenarios = ['hello', 'hi', 'good day'];

function Generate() {
  const randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * (scenarios.length));
  return scenarios[randomIndex];
}

function MostLikely() {
  const [randomString, setRandomString] = useState(Generate());

  const generateRandomString = useCallback(() => {
    setRandomString(Generate());
  }, []);


  return (
    <ImageBackground
      source={require('../../../assets/banner.jpg')}
      style={styles.image}
    >
      <Text>{randomString}</Text>
      <Button title="Generate" onPress={generateRandomString} />
    </ImageBackground>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that helped a lot to understand how this works.

Answer (score 1):

`Generate()` returns a random number, which you should use to index your array:

```
<Button title='Generate' onPress={() => console.log(scenario[Generate()])} />
```

Comment: Thank you, how do I add it to there though <Text>{}</Text> ?